# Collapse expander, when one list item is in open- Windows uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am using an expand panel to expand/collapse a list.

My problem is, at a time only one item only in expanded state. In my case if i expand one item without collapsing and i expand other item, then both the list items are in expanded state only, previous expanded item didn,t get collapse.

[image]
Refer image. If you see the image, all the 3 items are in expanded state only. Without automatic collapse

Here is my code:

ExpandPanel.cs:

```
public ExpandPanel()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ExpandPanel);
        }

        private bool _useTransitions = true;
        private VisualState _collapsedState;
        public Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton toggleExpander;
        private FrameworkElement contentElement;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderContent", typeof(object),
        typeof(ExpandPanel), null);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool),
        typeof(ExpandPanel), new PropertyMetadata(true, IsExpanded_Changed));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius),
        typeof(ExpandPanel), null);

        public object HeaderContent
        {
            get { return GetValue(HeaderContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
        }

        public CornerRadius CornerRadius
        {
            get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void IsExpanded_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var panel = (ExpandPanel)sender;
            panel.changeVisualState(false);
        }

        public void changeVisualState(bool useTransitions)
        {
            if (IsExpanded)
            {
                if (contentElement != null)
                {
                    contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Expanded", useTransitions);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Collapsed", useTransitions);
                _collapsedState = (VisualState)GetTemplateChild("Collapsed");
                if (_collapsedState == null)
                {
                    if (contentElement != null)
                    {
                        contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            toggleExpander = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton)
                GetTemplateChild("ExpandCollapseButton");
            if (toggleExpander != null)
            {
                toggleExpander.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    IsExpanded = !IsExpanded;
                    toggleExpander.IsChecked = IsExpanded;
                    changeVisualState(_useTransitions);
                };
            }
            contentElement = (FrameworkElement)GetTemplateChild("Content");
            if (contentElement != null)
            {
                _collapsedState = (VisualState)GetTemplateChild("Collapsed");
                if ((_collapsedState != null) && (_collapsedState.Storyboard != null))
                {
                    _collapsedState.Storyboard.Completed += (object sender, object e) =>
                    {
                        contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    };
                }
            }
            changeVisualState(false);
        }
```

xaml code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black" Margin="5,5,5,0" CornerRadius="5">
                                        <local:ExpandPanel x:Name="weekExpandPanel" HeaderContent="வார பலன்கள்" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False" FontWeight="ExtraBold">
                                            <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="weekAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
                                            </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                        </local:ExpandPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black" Margin="5,5,5,0" CornerRadius="5">
                                        <local:ExpandPanel x:Name="monthExpandPanel" HeaderContent="தமிழ் மாத ஜோதிடம்" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False" FontWeight="ExtraBold">
                                            <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="monthlyAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
                                            </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                        </local:ExpandPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black" Margin="5,5,5,0" CornerRadius="5">
                                        <local:ExpandPanel x:Name="yearExpandPanel" HeaderContent="ஆண்டு பலன்" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False" FontWeight="ExtraBold">
                                            <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="yearlyAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
                                            </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                                        </local:ExpandPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
```

.cs file:

```
weekAstrology.Text= "test";

monthlyAstrology.Text= "test1";
yearlyAstrology.Text= rootObject["ZodiacSignDetails"][0]["Astrotextyearly"].ToString();
```

my xaml code of custom control:

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExpandPanel" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExpandPanel">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="180" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid Margin="3">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}" FontSize="16"/>
                                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="ExpandCollapseButton">
                                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Ellipse Width="35" Height="35" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                    <Path RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Data="M2,3L9,10 16,3" Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedForegroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="4" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                                        <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateButtonTransform"/>
                                        </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" x:Name="Content">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

How to collapse one item if i click on other item.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want only one ExpandPanel to be opened in page(Other ExpandPanels will be closed automatically)? Could you maybe share a demo or post the Xaml codes of your usercontrol(ExpandPanel)?

Comment: yes, exactly. Only one expandpanel should be open one time and others should be close automatically. And i have shared my code in the question which i am using.

Comment: I mean the xaml codes of your ExpandPanel. I guess it's a userControl or a templated custom Control right? And for that there must be xaml codes for it. But I can only see the xaml codes that uses your control.

Comment: i am using the custom control in my xaml code like local:ExpandPanel. Nothing else i am using.

Comment: sorry @ElvisXia-MSFT, i have edited my question with custom control xaml code. Please look into it.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to collapse one item if i click on other item. Any help will be highly appreciated.

The easiest way is to register an `ExpandStateChanged` event for your custom control and collapse other `ExpandPanel` when any `ExpandPanel` expands.

You can follow the steps below to achieve this:

1. Register the `ExpandStateChanged` event in your custom control and invoke the event in `IsExpanded`'s Setter(ExpandPanel.cs):

   ```
   public sealed class ExpandPanel : ContentControl
   {
      public event EventHandler ExpandStateChanged;
      ...
      public bool IsExpanded
      {
           get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
           set
           {
               SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value);
               if (ExpandStateChanged != null)
               {
                   ExpandStateChanged(this,null);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Code the EventHandler in code-behind (MainPage.xaml.cs):

   ```
   private void ExpandStateChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var currentPanel = (ExpandPanel)sender;
       if (currentPanel.IsExpanded == false)
       {
           return;
       }
       foreach(var panel in panels)
       {
           if (panel.Name != currentPanel.Name)
           {
               panel.IsExpanded = false;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register the EventHandler `ExpandStateChanged="ExpandStateChangedHandler"` in Xaml (MainPage.xaml):

   ```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid Grid.Row="0">
       <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black" Margin="5,5,5,0" CornerRadius="5">
           <local:ExpandPanel x:Name="weekExpandPanel" HeaderContent="This is Header" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False" FontWeight="ExtraBold" ExpandStateChanged="ExpandStateChangedHandler">
               <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                   <TextBlock x:Name="weekAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
               </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
           </local:ExpandPanel>
       </Border>
   </Grid>

   <Grid Grid.Row="1">
       <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black" Margin="5,5,5,0" CornerRadius="5">
           <local:ExpandPanel x:Name="monthExpandPanel" HeaderContent="தமிழ் மாத ஜோதிடம்" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False" FontWeight="ExtraBold" ExpandStateChanged="ExpandStateChangedHandler">
               <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                   <TextBlock x:Name="monthlyAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
               </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
           </local:ExpandPanel>
       </Border>
   </Grid>

   <Grid Grid.Row="2">
       <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black" Margin="5,5,5,0" CornerRadius="5">
           <local:ExpandPanel x:Name="yearExpandPanel" HeaderContent="ஆண்டு பலன்" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsExpanded="False" FontWeight="ExtraBold" ExpandStateChanged="ExpandStateChangedHandler">
               <local:ExpandPanel.Content>
                   <TextBlock x:Name="yearlyAstrology" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
               </local:ExpandPanel.Content>
           </local:ExpandPanel>
       </Border>
   </Grid>
   ```

Here is the result:
[image]

Here is the complete sample: [ExpandCollapseSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/ExpandCollapseSample)